# Why do we say “in” a movie but “on” a TV show?

Tags: etymology, prepositions

When referring to a television program, my experience tells me that it is proper to use “on” whether I’m referring to an actor **on** the show or events **on** the show or anything.

> Did you see Matt Damon **on** Saturday Night Live? The sketches **on** that show are funny.

With films, on the other hand, I always hear people using “in” for the same purposes.

> Did you see Matt Damon **in** Good Will Hunting? The scenes **in** that film are powerful.

It could just be a trend that caught on in either case, but I’d love to know if there’s a definite explanation for this use of these prepositions or if there has been any scholarly work on the topic.

Comment: Movies are containers and TV shows are surfaces, just like days of the week are surfaces (*on* Tuesday) and months are containers (*in* January), and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that before movies and TVs people acted **in** plays, **on** a stage. Plays became movies and the TV became a sort of small personal stage we have in our houses. We turn it **on** with a switch, and while it's running we refer to it as being **on**. It seems to follow naturally that we would say "What's on TV tonight?" "Saturday Night Live is on."

On the other hand, characters and scenes are **in** plays and movies the same as they are **in** a book. A book or a film is a closed entity that contains things, so things are **in** it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is because TV shows are ongoing, and movies aren't. Movies were made once and that's it, while a TV show is continuously being produced.

This seems to be similar to how you would refer to being in a train. If the train is moving, you are on the train. If the train is stationary, you are in a train.

Just a thought.

Comment: I think that's a big part of it.  The choice of preposition is influenced by the more common usage, even in cases where it wouldn't technically apply (e.g. even if television show was a one-off, someone describing a person's appearance would usually use "on", but when identifying a subset of a television show's run [e.g. "season three of Frasier"] one would say "in").

Comment: You can certainly be in a stationary train and on a moving one.